# Why MongoDB gives me errors in Unity?

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

[image]I'm trying to apply the MongoDB with [this unity tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tc5raxEFntw)
MongoDB bought **mLab**, so the signing into mongoDB is done via mongoDB atlas.

I've created a cluster with **AWS** (similarly to the GUI mLab has),

- On "Overview" tab hit the "CONNECT" button. Out of the three options:
  "Connect with the Mongo Shell" / "Connect Your Application" /
  "Connect with MongoDB Compass" - Connect Your Application looked the
  most relevant to the code you've provided.
- In: "Connect Your Application" you need to choose a driver: I chose C# / .NET (because this is a C# project), version 2.5 or later.
- Got "Connection string":
  `mongodb+srv://user_name:<password>@testmp-pkump.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`

Few things:

1. The project name is not "test" (as it says here, right before the retryWrites = true): `mongodb+srv://<user_name>:<password>@testmp-pkump.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`
2. I've passed this link to the code under: `private const string MONGO_URI` , and for user name I write the user I've added to the cluster, and for the password, I write the password I've added to the user in the cluster. - and not the user I've used to create the MongoDB account
3. Running the "Server" scene resolves with an error: =

> ArgumentException: Invalid keyword
>   'mongodb+srv://:@serverclientmp-1oqao.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retrywrites'.
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item (System.String
>   keyword, System.Object value)
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionStringNonOdbc
>   (System.String connectionString)
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionString
>   (System.String connectionString)
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString
>   (System.String value)
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionStringBuilder..ctor (System.String
>   connectionString) MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.ParseConnectionString
>   (System.String connectionString) MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor
>   (System.String connectionString) Mongo.Init () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Database/Mongo.cs:16) Server.Init () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:40) Server.Start () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Server.cs:28)

4. I've checked the firewall connection to the Cluster, 27017. The IP Whitelist allows all IP access. I've tried changing the "test" name they put in the URI, to the project names and it still gives the error.

Why do I have this error about connecting to MongoDB?

Comment: Username and password missing `mongodb+srv://:@serverclientmp-1oqao.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retrywrites` ?

Comment: I've inserted the username and the password and the database name but still an error appears.
I follow the instructions as they appear here, because I don't have MongoDB shell on my computer and I use the "Connect Your Application" (see picture above please)

Comment: Make sure that your drive compatible with Mongo3.6 https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/. In error its missing username and password your removed for posting here ?

Comment: I've removed from the post the username and the password